# Rails: In many-to-many relationship, how to access the creator of a model's instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constructor, many-to-many

Say I have model User and Pictures.

I can create a picture relevant to a certain user:

```
picture = user.pictures.create
```

Is there any way I can access the user instance on the creation of the particular picture?

eg. `picture.author.should == user.name`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your relationships setup correctly ie

```
class User
  has_many :pictures
end
class Picture
  belongs_to :user
end
```

you should be able to have

```
picture.user.name.should eq user.name
```

Comment: I should have made it more clear, sorry. Author is a variable that will change over time in the Picture model, and is not related to the user directly. 

The following code works, but I am trying to figure out a better way:
user.pictures.create(:author => user.name)

Also note that its a many-to-many relation. So picture.user would not work. I want to store the first creator of the picture (ie. author)